# Data looks bunched up on some subplots

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Some of my data looks bunched up for some reason despite all 3 data frames having the same parameters. I'm a bit lost on what to do here and was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Probably your data is text instead of numeric.

Comment: How many records have each dataframe?