# Is there a cmap which goes from transparant to black (or any other color)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I'm using the following `cmap="binary"` on a datasets with zeros and ones. The cmap goes from white to black. This results in the following figure:

Black and white figure:

[image]

Because I want to overlap this graph with an existing graph, I want to keep the black but make the white transparant.

Overlapping image with white:

[image]

Is there a cmap which goes from transparancy to black ?

I'm using the following code to plot the graphs:

`plt.pcolor(mp1,cmap="binary",alpha=0.5)`

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution!

```
            c_white = matplotlib.colors.colorConverter.to_rgba('white',alpha = 0)
            c_black= matplotlib.colors.colorConverter.to_rgba('black',alpha = 1)
            cmap_rb = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('rb_cmap',[c_white,c_black],512)
            
            
            pl = plt.pcolor(mp1,cmap=cmap_rb)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not too difficult to define your own RGBA colour-maps ([source](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormap-manipulation.html)). For example, to define a black colour map with linearly varying transparency:

```py
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

cmap = np.zeros([256, 4])
cmap[:, 3] = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
cmap = ListedColormap(cmap)
```

Example usage:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

x = 2 * np.pi * np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)

z = np.sin(x.reshape(1, -1) + x.reshape(-1, 1))

cmap = np.zeros([256, 4])
cmap[:, 3] = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
cmap = ListedColormap(cmap)

plt.figure()
plt.pcolormesh(z + 1, cmap='bwr', edgecolors=None)
plt.pcolormesh(np.fliplr(z), cmap=cmap, edgecolors=None)
plt.savefig("temp")
```

Output:

[image: Output image temp.png]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I found the solution in another way. But your code gave me inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

If `mp1` only has the values 0 and 1, and nothing inbetween, you can mask out the zeros and only plot the ones. `np.where(mp1 == 1, 1, np.nan)` will only show the ones. Using `vmin=0` will make sure 0 maps to the white of the 'binary' colormap  and `vmax=1` will map 1 to black.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mp0 = np.random.randn(15, 30).cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=0) # random backgroud
mp1 = np.zeros((15, 30)) # start with all zeros
mp1[np.random.randint(0, 15, 30), np.random.randint(0, 30, 30)] = 1 # set some random positions to 1

plt.pcolormesh(mp0, cmap='rainbow')
plt.pcolormesh(np.where(mp1 == 1, 1, np.nan), cmap='binary', vmin=0, vmax=1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: If this (or one of the other answers) solves your question, you might consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873110/data-looks-bunched-up-on-some-subplots) the answer.